# Making the output of +Indexes match a rewritten URL

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, .htaccess

I'm using `mod_rewrite` to map `/foo/bar/baz` to `/foo/qux` using

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /foo/
RewriteRule ^bar/baz$ bar/baz/ [L,R=permanent]
RewriteRule ^bar/baz/(.*) qux/$1 [L]
```

I want to allow indexes in `/foo/qux`, so I have `Options +Indexes` in `/foo/qux/.htaccess`.

The problem is that the index output reads "`Index of /foo/qux`" even when the URL used to access it is `/foo/bar/baz`. Ideally, I'd like the output to reflect the URL used (so either `/foo/qux` or `/foo/bar/baz`, depending). I'd settle for the output always saying "Index of `/foo/bar/baz`". Is there a way to do this using `mod_rewrite` or plain-vanilla Apache configuration options?

Comment: The only suggestion I can make is to use the P flag rather than L, although I can't be sure this will work and will be more complicated as it require mod_proxy installed.

Comment: Proxying doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't pure Apache configuration option, but as an alternative you could replace the Rewrites with symbolic links on the actual file system.  With Linux, you would use:

```
ln -s <target> <link_name>
```

Comment: This doesn't work: the whole point is to map baz in the component bar to another component qux that bar doesn't necessarily know about. I don't want any information about qux leaking into the bar hierarchy.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what exactly what you mean with this comment other than the 'its not what I want' part... (It is Friday :-) )  

The only other thing I recommend is that if you are already using mod_php you can find lots of generic directory listing code that will do the same thing that the Index directive does.  I would think it would be pretty easy to alter the php to display the file listing based on the URL requested.

Good luck, it is an interesting problem.  I wouldn't be surprised if there is a pure apache answer.

Comment: Sorry, I knew I wasn't being clear... I don't want explicit links from /foo/bar to /foo/qux because /foo/bar is being copied over from another project that has no need to know about the details of the filesystem layout on the web server. I want the web server configuration to handle it, rather than pushing those dependencies into the project.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it's possible, due to the order in which `mod_rewrite` and `mod_autoindex` handle the request. The path that `mod_autoindex` receives is and must be the "real" one.

Kyle's symlink workaround is the only solution I'm aware of.